# Docked attribute table not displayed when reopening a QGIS project

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgs, mapcanvas

I have created a project with multiple map views (canvases).
I have also opened vertically in the project an attribute table.

When I save and reopen the project, the layout is lost.

What can I do to keep the layout of the different map views and the docked attribute table?

My QGIS version is 3.10.

[image]